# MySQL: sort out periods without overlapping

Tags: mysql

I have a table looking as follows. I'd like to get only these rows which have non-overlapping time periods.

```
id, group, starttime, endtime
 1  A      2018-01-01   2018-01-04
 2  A      2018-01-02   2018-01-05
 3  A      2018-01-03   2018-01-07
 4  A      2018-01-05   2018-01-06
 5  A      2018-01-06   2018-01-09
 6  A      2018-01-08   2018-01-10
 7  B      2018-01-01   2018-01-04
 8  B      2018-01-03   2018-01-06
```

So in my example the result should contain id1, id4, id6 and id7 because they start a new period within the group which was not already 'used' before.

I have been trying to solve this for 3 days now and I cannot figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why isn't id5 being returned ?

Answer (score 0):

id5 is not being returned because the date 2018-01-06 is already covered by id4.

Has anyone an idea?
Thanks a lot!